# Background attachment scroll vs. fixed

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an image for background which is 2000px width. It is prepared in a following way: 1000px in the center for content, and additional 500px on the left and right for margins in higher resolution monitors.

I would like it to be centered on every resolution.

When I try it to do with `bg {background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed; }` image is properly centered, but it obviously do not scroll.

So I'm replacing `fixed` with `scroll`:
`bg {background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center top scroll; }` but than image is not centered - it starts displaying from top-left corner, so that in smaller resolutions you can see left margin, which shouldn't be visible.

Here is example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjr4Q/1/). Play with `background-attachment` values `scroll`/`fixed` and try to reduce size of result window and you will hopefully understand know what I mean.

Can you help me with solving this issue?

Comment: Or a [CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com). The CSS snippets you posted appear to be valid.

Comment: I've edited my question and added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `background-attachment` property like below

```
background-attachment:scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries. Something like this.

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {

#left-margin-div {
width:500px;
height:1700px; /*or whatever your height is*/
background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');
position:absolute;
left:-500px;
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
```